# Can I deal with outliers in my data by applying tanh(x)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics

I am working with financial data and cannot assume a Gaussian distribution. So I normalize my data by subtracting the median and dividing by the interquartile range. This puts 95% of the data into a range [-2,2]. The rest are a bunch of crazy outliers that can be as high as -8, 28, 47 etc.

But I still dont want to throw the outliers away. So I apply a tanh(x) to my entire normalized time series and the majority of the data that are in the range [-2,-2] are now mapped to [-0.95, 0.95], and the crazy outliers are now saturated close to -1 and 1, and the really crazy ones are all mapped to precisely -1 and 1. Order is kept throughout the process, because tanh(x) is a monotonic function. And the Machine Learning algorithm doesnt have to waste time and energy on numbers that have much larger absolute values than others. The extreme outliers are all now in two groups, -1 and 1.

By the way, the tanh compression doesnt destroy too many unique values. That is, close values are not collapsed to the same value by tanh. I get almost exatly the same amount of unique values in my time series before the tanh, as after.

The data will be fed into Neural Network, Random Forest, and Gradient Boosted Decision Trees. (Even though decision trees dont care too much about outliers, I still want to force all indicators into the same range [-1,1]).

What are the bad consequences to my approach, compared to just throwing the outliers away? What am I missing?

Comment: Do you want to be able to make accurate predictions for these outliers?

Comment: My assumption/intuition is that there is no big difference between 14 and 32 for outliers in financial data. They both tell us that this particular indicator is hot right now. I dont believe splitting hair in the tails matters.

Comment: You can cross-validate with and without the outliers to determine whether they improve the predictive accuracy.

Comment: (1) Maybe take logarithm of data before standardizing. Just a thought. (2) "Outlier" just means there is something going on which you have not accounted for. Is that not-accounted-something important or not? That's a question you can answer only by looking at results for your specific problem; you can't assume the answer from the start.